# How to make Pycharm show all git commit history for subfolders?

Tags: pycharm, git-history

Since some point (probably update) Pycharm stopped showing git history for one of project subfolders.

#### Question

**Does it have a functionality to enable all commit history for my sub-folder?**

I tried to check some options in:

```
File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git
```

But it did not help

Also, I checked different options from Git Log context menu, also no result.
I see commits for two days only but commits to this folder are done for at least during one month.
Is this a bug after update? Is some functionality available for such case, like restoring history?

#### PyCharm version

```
PyCharm 2021.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-211.6693.115, built on April 6, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.35 amd64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.8.0-48-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1917M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: PerforceIC (0.11.2), Docker (211.6693.111)
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

[image: Git commit history example]

Sorry,I had to blur some text.

Comment: which of the higher levels of nesting do the commits actually appear in? E.g. do they appear when you look at git log for `tests`, or the root of your whole project, etc

Comment: When I use Git -> Show history on root folder everything is shown.

Comment: I've just checked. I still do not see git history up specific date in subfolders, only in the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to see the whole history for my sub-folder after:

- Clicking File
- Invalidate Caches
- Check 'Clear downloaded shared indexes'
- Invalidate and Restart.

[image]

I think this issue was connected to IDE update.